# Concatenate Multiple Responses from JavaScript XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, scope, xmlhttprequest, string-concatenation

I have HTML content from two different URLs that I need to append to one HTML element.

Using JavaScript ES5, I am attempting to create a string variable, and simply concatenate the result of two HTTP requests.

When I am done with my requests, I want this variable to have the following string value:

```
<script src='foo/bar/script.js'></script><div>content</div>
```

I then want to take that variable and append it (using jQuery) to an HTML element in my page. The end goal is to fill a div with the result of two HTTP requests, like so:

```
<div class="target-element">
    <script src='foo/bar/script.js'></script><div>content</div>
</div>
```

What I don't understand in my code is why it is that my console.log in `storeHttpResult` reflects the `combinedHttpResult` variable as I expect it to be, but in `getContent`, `combinedHttpResult` is not modified.

```
var libsLocation = 'http://some/location/libs.html'; //contents: <script src='foo/bar/script.js'>
var htmlLocation = 'http://some/location/snippet.html'; //contents: <div>content</div>
var combinedHttpResult = '';

// taken from David Flanagan JavaScript book, p499:
function getText(url, callback) { 
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();         
    request.open('GET', url);                   
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {   
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
            var type = request.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
            if (type.match(/^text/))            // make sure the response is text
                callback(request.responseText); // pass it to the callback
        }
    };
    request.send(null);
}
function storeHttpResult(e) {   
    console.log('before: ' + combinedHttpResult);
    combinedHttpResult += e;   
    console.log('after: ' + combinedHttpResult);
}
function getContent(libLoc, htmlLoc) {
    console.log('**** ' + combinedHttpResult);
    if ($('.target-element').length > 0 ) {
        $('.target-element').each(function() {
            getText(libLoc, storeHttpResult);
            getText(htmlLoc, storeHttpResult);

            $(this).append(combinedHttpResult); // empty string - why?
        });
    }
    console.log('~~~~ ' + combinedHttpResult);
}
getContent(libsLocation, htmlLocation);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of race condition. To understand clearly the nature of your problem, you have to understand how "[Event Loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&vl=en)" in javascript works.

Long story short (hoping that you will watch that video) is that your code is not executed in the order it is written.

What you expect is that when you invoke getText(), it will invoke all the underlying functions, but the execution flow here is a bit out of sync. Here is what happens when you invoke getText(libLoc, storeHttpResult);

- storeHttpResult is invoked
- an instane of XMLHttpRequest is created
- a handler for the event 'onreadystatechange' of XMLHttpRequest is registered
- getText(htmlLoc, storeHttpResult) is invoked

Note that the last step is invocation of the next expression on getContent. storeHttpResult will be executed when the request is done, and there is no way you could predict that when it is going to happen.

In this case solutions for such async. operations are created. The simples one are [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). It depends what browser you have to support, but if it happens to be a modern one than I highly recommend using Promises.

Using promises the solution could look something like this :

```
function getText(url) { 
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();         
      request.open('GET', url);                   
      request.onreadystatechange = function() {   
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
            var type = request.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
            if (type.match(/^text/))            // make sure the response is text
                resolve(request.responseText); // pass it to the callback
        }
      };
      request.send(null);
    });
}

function getContent(libLoc, htmlLoc) {
    console.log('**** ' + combinedHttpResult);
    if ($('.target-element').length > 0 ) {
        $('.target-element').each(function() {
            var self = this;
            Promise.all([getText(libLoc), getText(htmlLoc)]).then(function(response){
              $(self).append(response[0]);
              $(self).append(response[1]);
            });
        });
    }
    console.log('~~~~ ' + combinedHttpResult);
}
getContent(libsLocation, htmlLocation);
```

Note that there are some things that can be improved with this code, but understanding how to handle Promises is a very good start.

Other solutions exists such as [Generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) and [Observables](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs) if you want to dig even deeper in the topic.

Comment: I believe the Promise.all line needs brackets like so (otherwise there is an error): **Promise.all([getText(libLoc), getText(htmlLoc)]).then(function(response){...** 

But thanks for this excellent answer. I did watch the illuminating video. I have a lot to study when it comes to event loop and promises, including your code here.